# High accuracy clock source for Orange Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, clock, ntp, orange-pi

We're trying to have time-keeping as close to real-time as possible. Since our network doesn't support PTP, I'm using NTP. We have an NTP-server with GPS at disposal, and we're syncing about every minutes.

Though we still experience a little drift - of course. But some of our hardware drifts more than others. The best drifts about 1/10th of a ms where as other drift as much as 1.5ms.

We would like to hit around 0.25ms 90% of the time. 
Does anyone know if it is possible to change the crystal on the board to a more accurate crystal, or have an idea how to make the clock drift less?

Best regards.

Comment: You missed an important number: how many minutes is "syncing about every minutes"? if 10 minutes then 1.5ms drift is 2.5ppm from nominal, if spread between + and -1.5ms, that's 5ppm accuracy which is pretty good for a stock crystal.

Comment: Keep the crystal at a fixed/stabilised temperature will be the best way to stabilise it (for a cheap crystal) - keep the unit running with the board in a relatively closed box and after some hours the temperature will get to fairly steady state, but +/- 5 degrees change might easily cause -/+2.5ppm or +/-2.5ppm frequency change.

Comment: @barny we're syncing every 60 second. 
The problem just seems, that even though we keep a constant temp (+/- 2 C), some hw-platforms drift more than others. This is kind of expected, since the hardware is pretty cheap. Using a real time clock, the results get a littlle ... weird: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296554/ntp-and-rtc-hw-clock-weird-results